# MDW performance_counter_instances table running out of identity values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, identity, data-collection

My MDW database's performance_counter_instances table has run out of identity values.

Has anyone ever encountered this?

Is it safe to change the data type of the identity field performance_counter_id from INT to BIGINT without breaking anything?

Bonus Question - What is the impact of this field running out of identity values?

I can't find anything useful about this issue online.

I have converted the data type to BIGINT using [this script](http://pastebin.com/FSbRuu1v) and now all of the collection_set_2_upload jobs are failing with the following error message:

> LKU - Lookup into performance_counter_instances to obtain performance_counter_id for all counter paths that get inserted.Outputs[Lookup Match Output].Columns[performance_counter_id] and reference column named "performance_counter_id" have incompatible data types.

Please let me know if this is something that can be fixed or if I will have to just eventually recreate the MDW database again.  This happens about once every 6 months in my environment.  For now I've reseeded the identity to -2147483647 to buy some time.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('snapshots.performance_counter_instances', RESEED, -2147483647)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you exhaust the upper bound of `INT` you will receive, for every new insert:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting IDENTITY to data type int.
Arithmetic overflow occurred.
```

**Outside of the MDW use case**

Converting to `BIGINT` is far safer (IMHO) than what some people do - go back to 0 and fill in the gaps, or go to -2 billion and just delay dealing with it until you use the same number of values one more time. If 2 billion rows isn't enough, neither is 4 billion. If you use compression changing the data type for values < 2 billion will actually save you some space.

However you will come across issues if this is part of a primary key constraint, referenced by foreign keys, has other constraints, etc. You'll need to perform some extra work in addition to just changing the data type.

**For MDW specifically**

The problem with the solution above, for MDW specifically, is that the data collector package (`SSIS Packages/Data Collector/PerfCountersUpload`) includes some logic that relies on the underlying data type to be `INT`. So, the collector jobs fail because of this mismatch.

This should buy you some time:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('snapshots.performance_counter_instances', RESEED, -2147483648);
```

And between now and when you start approaching 0 again (you should set up some kind of monitoring to check the max value and send some kind of alert when you get close), go in and clean up and make sure there are no positive values.

Then, when you start approaching 2 billion again, clean out all the negative values, and reseed.

Is this annoying? Absolutely. I think this might be one of several reasons why you don't see a very large MDW adoption.

Comment: ok, this actually doesn't answer the question because, as I feared, once I converted the data type to BIGINT now all of my MDW upload jobs are failing with the following error " LKU - Lookup into performance_counter_instances to obtain performance_counter_id for all counter paths that get inserted.Outputs[Lookup Match Output].Columns[performance_counter_id] and reference column named "performance_counter_id" have incompatible data types."

Comment: @Alf47 *shrug* sorry, in most cases changing to `BIGINT` will not cause a problem, but MDW is horrendously fragile, and some of this logic is fixed to data types in the SSIS packages (which I have no clue how to modify - I had to look up the spelling of SSIS). Maybe instead you could change back to `INT`, and then run `DBCC CHECKIDENT` with `RESEED` and setting the seed to -2 billion. You'll run out again but by then maybe you can clear out all of the positive values manually.

Comment: [SSIS Package Extract from MSDB](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/ssis-package-extract-from-msdb.html) You can build out your dtutil calls to pull those packages from the MSDB. Ensure you're using the correct DTUTIL if you have more than 2012 installed on your machine. Default path will be `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\dtutil.exe`